# Python 2.7 is not keeping its ulimits after an exec?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exec, ulimit

I don't understand why Python is not keeping its ulimits when you do an exec. I created this small testcase:

```
import os
import resource

print "Heap limit:", resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_DATA)
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_DATA, (100, -1))
print "Heap limit:", resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_DATA)
os.execve("/bin/ls", ["/bin/ls","/etc/passwd"], dict())
```

The output in my Ubuntu 14.04 (Python 2.7.6) is:

```
Heap limit: (-1, -1)
Heap limit: (100, -1)
/etc/passwd
```

Of course, you can't execute an ls with that amount of virtual memory:

```
$ sh -c "ulimit -v 100; ls /etc/passwd"
Killed
```

Comment: `execve` doesn't create a new process; it simply replaces the code in the current process with new code.

Comment: Thanks, i think i fixed the explanation.

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think that since the process was started without a limit on the heap space it could use, it already has already received enough memory from the OS for `ls` to succeed. That is, the OS doesn't care what the process does with the memory it already has, or the attempt to set the limit to a value less than the memory currently available to the OS would probably fail as well.

Comment: Uhm, odd since setrlimit is not failing, but the best explanation so far .. (i have no idea!)

Comment: In fact, if you change the example to start another python script, but executing:

    x = [1.0]*100000
    print x[50000]

It will work. So i don't think it is only used already allocated memory..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that [RLIMIT_DATA is deprecated](http://linuxfollies.blogspot.com.ar/2010/10/more-on-rlimitdata-vs-rlimitas.html). Now we should use RLIMIT_AS. If you change the script to use it, it will work as expected.